# Takes forever to read and flatten 100K+ json files

Tags: json, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have large number of json file that i have to read, flatten and filter (select specific key-value). below is the code i am using

```
for i in range(len(json_files)):   # is the list of json files in directory
    text = []
    for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
        with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file: # path_to_json is json directory
            jtext = json.load(json_file)
            json_text=jtext['KEY_TO_FILTER']
            text_json=flatten_data(json_text)  # function i'm using to select specific key in json
            text.append(text_json)
```

i really appreciate hint how to use multiprocessing. any other suggestion ow to speed up the process is very welcomed

Comment: Worth mentioning that unless your files are really large and complex it seems likely that the bottleneck is not processor speed but disk I/O so doing multiprocessing here might not actually help much. First thing I'd do is write down how fast I actually need things to be. Then I might be something like using a complied tool like jq. If still off by an order of magnitude I'd look to distribute the load between multiple machines.

Comment: I think there are too many angles to go about this. For example: does it need to be python? I would assume that a solution in go or even java could be equally simple, but perform much better. And yes, the **first** thing to understand is: where does your code spend its time? File implies IO, and IO implies: just throwing (many more) threads at won't necessarily be the improvement you are looking for. If this is for a task that you need to do more than once, then you really might think "bigger". As in: can you distribute your files to more than one machine, so that you can actually do ...

Comment: many file reads from different disks? Which of course requires you to rethink how your files get to the different systems, and so on.

Comment: Why is there the first `for i in range(len(json_files))` loop? Each iteration of this loop you're opening and flattening the same files - this takes time and can be cached.

Comment: I fixed it yet I still it shows MemoryError